# Cannot plot anything or display pylab frame in new process using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing

Does anyone have any idea why the code below won't even open up a pylab figure window? If the body of the test function is moved to the main process it works fine, but I'd like to do some plotting from within a new process specifically.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from pylab import *

def test():
    frac = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 40]
    labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    ion()
    hold(False)
    while True:
        pie(frac, labels = labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
        title('test', bbox={'facecolor' : '0.8', 'pad' : 5})
        draw()


p1 = Process(target = test)
p1.daemon = True
p1.start()

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: I find the plotting in the infinite loops upsetting....

Comment: OK, the loop is to be supplied with new plotting data from a pipe later, but that has nothing to do with the main problem, i.e. that no figure window is shown at all.

Comment: Hmm, your code works for me... the figure is showing up. But it's eating up my cpu at 100%, so I'm guessing that's the root of your problem.

Comment: Try putting a `pause(1)` in the loop.  You may just not be letting the gui main-loop ever get a chance to draw the figure.

Comment: Aha, what version of python and matplotlib are you using and what os? I use python 2.7.3, matplotlib 1.1.1rc and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Adding a pause in the plotting loop doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move all the GUI statements -- including the import statement -- into `test`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def test():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    frac = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 40]
    labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    plt.pie(frac, labels = labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
    plt.title('test', bbox={'facecolor' : '0.8', 'pad' : 5})
    plt.show()    

p1 = mp.Process(target = test)
p1.daemon = True
p1.start()
p1.join()
```

Use `p1.join()` instead of `while True: pass`. It is much less CPU-intensive.

Finally, be sure to read the [Matplotlib animation cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations) for examples on how to do animation right.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code eats away at your CPU, so that why you're not getting the figure to show up. I changed your code a little bit, mainly getting rid of while(1) loops. Does this work for you?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from pylab import *

def test():
    frac = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 40]
    labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    ion()
    hold(False)
    pie(frac, labels = labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
    title('test', bbox={'facecolor' : '0.8', 'pad' : 5})
    draw()

p1 = Process(target = test)
p1.daemon = True
p1.start()

import time
time.sleep(5)
```